# Assign datetime value to today's date with specific time

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a variable which is defined as a `DateTime`. I need to assign it today's date but have the time be 4 PM. How do I do this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You want `DateTime.Today.AddHours(16)`

`DateTime.Today` will return today's date at midnight.
You can also use the `Date` property to drop the time from an arbitrary `DateTime` value.

Comment: So what happens at 1 am when this is run? Seems like it will set the time to the next day at 4 am. Doesn't seem right to me

Comment: @Cole9350: No; it will return 4 PM.

Answer (score 19):

I think this should do what you need...

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime dt = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, 16, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var anotherTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(16.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at all the [overloaded constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) for DateTime.

```
DateTime myDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, 16, 0, 0);
```

Edit: Correction. Thanks Jon. :)

Comment: Overloaded, not overridden. Constructors can't be overridden as they're not polymorphic to start with.

Comment: What if this is run so close to midnight that the first Today call is different to one of the subsequent ones?